# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found upon clicking Submit button with form tag in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've created a simple form in my html file with a submit button for a username and password but upon clicking the submit button **TOMCAT shows an error**

> "The origin server did not find a current representation for the
>   target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

I tried changing the url-pattern and servlet-name still and none of it works.

Here is the **web.xml** file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>DemoWebCRUDApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>HomePage.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name >
    <servlet-class>com.demoCRUD.servlet.UserLoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginValidation</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**HomePage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body> 

    Login Form
    <form action="/loginValidation" method ="get">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
        <br>
        Password: <input type="text" name="password"/>
        <br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the **UserLoginServlet**

```
package com.demoCRUD.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.demoCRUD.dao.UserDAO;


public class UserLoginServlet extends HttpServlet 
{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("username"));
        String password = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("password"));

    }
}
```

Here is the setup for the Project

[image]

Comment: What `URL` you are trying to access and also change your form `action=loginValidation`

Comment: I tried changing it to action="loginValidation" and action=loginValidation and still it doesn't work. I am trying to access the /loginValidation url I created in the web.xml file for the loginServlet

Comment: this is the working project of mine with servlets on github try this https://github.com/rosmahajan/java-servlet

Comment: Thank you Messrs I found the solution. I changed the action="/loginValidation" to "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/loginValidation". I don't know why the path changes but it works.

Answer (score 1):

One of the comments to your question is correct. The following will do the trick.

Just make sure to reload your page on the browser before you try submitting.

```
Login Form
    <form action="loginValidation" method ="get">
        Username: <input name="username"/>
        <br>
        Password: <input name="password"/>
        <br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
    </form>
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you sir. Great knowledge sometimes I forgot to refresh the server and clean the project before running the wab app again

Answer (score 0):

The servlet never writes a response back to the browser.  Write a response within the `doGet` method using the `PrintWriter`.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("username"));
    String password = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("password"));
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
}
```